# Tips on using Mootools Swiff object to talk between JS and Flash Movie?

Tags: flash, mootools

I'm trying to use Mootool's Swiff object to load a flash movie and to start talking with it. I've been following the example here:

http://mootools.net/blog/2008/02/12/whats-new-in-12-swiff/#more-63

Which I know is a little out of date (the events option should be callBacks apparently) but should at least be a start. Yet I can't get the thing working one bit. No JS errors, firebug says its loaded SWF from my server at least but no alerts! Whats missing?

Actionscript:

```
//(ActionScript)
import flash.external.*;

function echoText(text) {
    ExternalInterface.call('alert', "This message is from Flash: "+text);   
}

ExternalInterface.addCallback( "echoText", this, echoText );

//Fires the 'onLoad' event within the Swiff object.
ExternalInterface.call(_root.onLoad);
```

My JS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Terris test console</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var obj;

            window.addEvent( "domready", function() {
                //(JavaScript)
                obj = new Swiff('interface.swf', {
                    width:  1,
                    height: 1,
                    container: $('swiffContainer'),
                    callBacks: {
                        onLoad: function() {
                            alert("Flash is loaded!")
                        }
                    }
                });
            });


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using Mootools 1.2.2 from here http://mootools.net/download

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 coz: container: $('swiffContainer') it's what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you need a

```
<div id='swiffContainer'></div>
```

somewhere in your body?

Comment: Doh! That works, I'm still having trouble with MooSwiff though but at least its working. Sorry for the late acceptance, been away :)